# Differentiating in-buit System Types with custom classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way by which we differentiate between the in-buit System Types (String, List etc) with custom classes in C# ?

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by "in-built system types" better. Do you mean all the types from System.* namespaces?

Comment: For example if I have my custom class Person, then it should not return this class while searching all the "in-built types". This will help me differentiate whenever I have an object of Person.

Comment: Yes, but should it return System.Xml.XmlReader? How about System.Windows.UIElement? What if you create a custom Person class but put it in the System namespace? As @Konrad Rudolph says, there's no meaningful distinction between what you call "in-built" system types and other types, so you'll have to be clearer on this. Maybe you could explain what you're planning to use this distinction for? Maybe there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Type.Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly.aspx) to see which assembly it comes from, or you can use [`Type.Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace.aspx) to get the namespace. The rest depends on your definition of "built-in". For example, you could say that

```
var builtIn = someType.Namespace.StartsWith("System");
```

But there is no "hard" definition for what you want.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from putting your own types into the `System` namespace though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Definitely. But it's like putting your types into `namespace std`: it's not something that should happen in practice.

Comment: with the difference that putting anything in `namespace std` is actually illegal: programs that do that are broken, regardless of whether a compiler accepts that. In .NET, there’s no hard rule restricting that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Again, you are technically right. But in practice it does happen (I 've seen it). As a practical solution, and as long as I 'm not writing code that is responsible for human lives, I 'd be willing to go with a coarse check because an airtight check would probably be YAGNI.

Answer (score 2):

There is no logical and meaningful difference between built-in types and custom types.

The only difference is that the built-in types reside in the `mscorlib` assembly or one of the other framework assemblies. You can check for that, nothing more. However, I would question the usefulness of this information (due to what I said above).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I was just trying to automap my properties between two different objects like NamespaceA.Person and NamespaceB.Person. As you see we can easily implement the properties if both have similar primitive types. But if NamespaceA.Person has a property of Type Employee while NamespaceB.Person only has a field EmployeeId (of type long) mapping to it, then how do I make the function understand that it has encountered a class and it should not map the class to the property of type long ?? Instead it should search within this class for the long property.